# SVG strange behavior in IE10+

Tags: debugging, svg, cross-browser, internet-explorer-10, internet-explorer-11

I'm using svg patterns to define custom background images for the fill attribute in svg's later in the page. I'm hiding the original svg and pattern definitions at the top of the page.

- IE9 has no issues
- IE10 doesn't show anything
- IE11 working in fiddle, but in production only shows last one on page

Here is a stripped down example: http://jsfiddle.net/CCFWj/3/

```
<div style="height:0px; overflow:hidden">
    <svg version="1.1" x="0px" y="0px" width="0" height="0" viewBox="0 0 140 155">
        <defs>  
            <pattern id="oil-gas" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="186" height="206">
                <image xlink:href="http://megastaging.com/erc/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/Oil_1-500x554-1390485365.jpg" x="0" y="0" width="186" height="206"></image>
            </pattern>
            <pattern id="marine" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="186" height="206">
                <image xlink:href="http://megastaging.com/erc/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Marine_Header-500x554-1390486195.jpg" x="0" y="0" width="186" height="206"></image>
            </pattern>                                          
        </defs>
    </svg>

    <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="140px" height="154.046px" viewBox="0 0 140 154.046" enable-background="new 0 0 140 154.046" xml:space="preserve">
    <path id="hex-140-155" d="M78.113,152.144c-4.431,2.531-11.684,2.537-16.118,0.016l-53.869-30.63c-4.434-2.522-8.067-8.718-8.071-13.769
    L0,46.407c-0.004-5.051,3.617-11.252,8.047-13.782l53.81-30.724c4.43-2.529,11.684-2.536,16.118-0.014l53.867,30.628
    c4.435,2.522,8.153,9.322,8.158,14.374l-0.031,60.748c0.005,5.051-3.615,11.253-8.046,13.783L78.113,152.144z">            </path>
    </svg>
</div>

<svg class="image" viewBox="0 0 140 155" width="140px" height="155px">
    <use xlink:href="#hex-140-155" fill="url(#oil-gas)"></use>
</svg>                      
<svg class="image" viewBox="0 0 140 155" width="140px" height="155px">
    <use xlink:href="#hex-140-155" fill="url(#marine)"></use>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft SVG deviations are vague on the subject of the `pattern` element:

> The display property affects pattern elements and references to those pattern elements

On the subject of `xml:space`:

> The xml:space attribute is not supported in SVG.

So `xml:space` and `pattern` deviations may cause no side-effects in one version of IE, but several side-effects in another.

**References**

- [MS-SVG:2.1.16 [SVG11] Section 13.3, Patterns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg558019)
- [MS-SVG:2.1.1 [SVG11] Section 5.10.2, The xml:lang and xml:space attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg557993)